# AWS .NET SDK Direct Upload to S3 - Pre Signed URL

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, sdk

I'm trying to understand if a particular .NET SDK example ([seen here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html)) for uploading files to S3 is first uploaded to my server, or if it is uploaded directly to S3?

I suspect the file is first uploaded to my server and then saved to S3. But perhaps the SDK magically bypasses my server? Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;

namespace s3.amazon.com.docsamples
{
    class UploadObjcetUsingPresignedURL
    {
        static IAmazonS3 s3Client;
        // File to upload.
        static string filePath   = "*** Specify file to upload ***";
        // Information to generate pre-signed object URL.
        static string bucketName = "*** Provide bucket name ***";
        static string objectKey  = "*** Provide object key for the new object ***";

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
                {
                    string url = GeneratePreSignedURL();
                    UploadObject(url);

                }
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
            {
                if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null &&
                    (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId")
                    ||
                    amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Check the provided AWS Credentials.");
                    Console.WriteLine(
                    "To sign up for service, go to http://aws.amazon.com/s3");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                     "Error occurred. Message:'{0}' when listing objects",
                     amazonS3Exception.Message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        static void UploadObject(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            httpRequest.Method = "PUT";
            using (Stream dataStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8000];
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        dataStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        }

        static string GeneratePreSignedURL()
        {
            GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key        = objectKey,
                    Verb       = HttpVerb.PUT,
                    Expires    = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5)
                };

            string url = null;
            url = s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
            return url;
        }
    }
}
```

**So again, the question is**
Does the above example first upload to the server, then transfer the file to S3? Or does it somehow bypass the server and upload directly to S3?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
As TJ said, the answer is yes it will first go through my server before it gets to Amazon. Kinda feels like a dumb question now. 
In case anyone is interested, I decided to use CORS AJAX uploading with Presigned URLs to S3. Pretty complicated at first but I now have it working. So my server can sit back and relax while zillions of uploads occur simultaneously!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this line :

```
while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
```

The bytes are read into your server (not persisted on disk, but remain in-memory) before being written to the output stream. So, your server is not bypassed.

Comment: Thanks @TJ. I suspected that might be the case